# C# unique items in a nested list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model like below

```cs
public class Path
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<Path> Items {get; set;}
}
```

& a list data representation of individual item in `List<Path>` as below

```cs
new List<path>
{
  new Path
  {
    Name = "FirstRoot",
    Items = new List<Path>
    {
      new Path
      {
        Name = "2023",
        Items = new List<Path>
        {
          new Path
          {
            Name = "01",
            Items = new List<Path>
            {
              new Path
              {
                Name = "01"
                Items = new List<Path>
                {
                  new Path
                  {
                    Name = "01.text"
                    Items = null,
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  new Path
  {
    Name = "FirstRoot",
    Items = new List<Path>
    {
      new Path
      {
        Name = "2023",
        Items = new List<Path>
        {
          new Path
          {
            Name = "01",
            Items = new List<Path>
            {
              new Path
              {
                Name = "01"
                Items = new List<Path>
                {
                  new Path
                  {
                    Name = "02.text"
                    Items = null,
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
...
}
```

```
- FirstRoot - 2023 - 01 - 01.text
- FirstRoot - 2023 - 01 - 02.text
- SecondRoot - 2023 - 01 - 01.text
- SecondRoot - 2023 - 01 - 02.text
- ThirdRoot - 2023 - 01.text
- ThirdRoot - 2023 - 02.text
```

Now how do i get the unique path out of this so that my list looks like

```cs
new List<path>
{
  new Path
  {
    Name = "FirstRoot",
    Items = new List<Path>
    {
      new Path
      {
        Name = "2023",
        Items = new List<Path>
        {
          new Path
          {
            Name = "01",
            Items = new List<Path>
            {
              new Path
              {
                Name = "01"
                Items = new List<Path>
                {
                  new Path
                  {
                    Name = "01.text"
                    Items = null,
                  },
                  new Path
                  {
                    Name = "02.text"
                    Items = null,
                  },
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  new Path
  {
    Name = "SecondRoot",
    Items = new List<Path>
    {
      new Path
      {
        Name = "2023",
        Items = new List<Path>
        {
          new Path
          {
            Name = "01",
            Items = new List<Path>
            {
              new Path
              {
                Name = "01"
                Items = new List<Path>
                {
                  new Path
                  {
                    Name = "01.text"
                    Items = null,
                  },
                  new Path
                  {
                    Name = "02.text"
                    Items = null,
                  },
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
...
}
```

I tried to look at [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1032175/How-to-find-all-occurance-of-a-particular-entity-f) solution, but could not find one.

Comment: What have you done and where are you stuck? *"I want to do X, show me how"* is not a question for SO. You need to understand the logic you're trying to implement before writing code to implement it but there's no evidence that you've put any thought into that logic yet, so you haven't encountered an actual issue yet.

Comment: Where is ThirdRoot in your sample answer? Given that it has a different format, knowing how you expect it to map would be good...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a working code, posting it here if it helps anyone.

```cs
        private IEnumerable<Path> CleanPaths(IEnumerable<Path> items)
        {
            IEnumerable<Path> result = Enumerable.Empty<Path>();
            List<Path> distinctItems = new List<Path>();
            var distincts = items.Select(i => i.Name).Distinct().ToArray();

            foreach (var item in distincts)
            {
                var childs = items
                    .Where(j => j.Name == item && j.Items != null)
                    .SelectMany(k => k.Items)
                    .ToList();

                distinctItems.Add(new Path
                {
                    Name = item,
                    Items = CleanPaths(childs),
                });
            }

            result = distinctItems;

            return result;
        }
```